# DEM provided contains high elevations (trees) that I wish to remove - is this possible

Tags: raster, dem, geotiff-tiff, rivers, qgis2threejs

I wish to remove trees off my 3D aerial (high elevations). The files provided are  .tif - unfortunately the trees are causing quite a bit of noise. Is there a way to set an elevation to remove them? Area is not very sloped so the trees would be chopped.

I also have a regional .tif which does not include the trees - could i stack both .tif together to somehow remove the trees...

Sorry i am fairly new to QGIS any help would be wonderful.

Comment: Depending on your DEM, e.g. if it is fine-res, you might try this: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323003064_A_new_method_for_the_removal_of_off-terrain_objects_from_LiDAR-derived_raster_surface_models

Comment: Where did your DEM come from (actually, it's not a DEM it's a DTM because it contains above ground objects).. if you generated if from LiDAR try reprocessing it using only the ground classes. If not you could try removing anything that's excessive from your regional DEM but it gets more difficult when you try to fill the holes you will make.

Comment: A thought: Although XYZ is a very wasteful format you could convert your elevation raster to this format with GDAL_Translate -of XYZ which can then be used by lastools to perform lasground https://rapidlasso.com/lastools/lasground/ (be sure to output LAS format or this step does nothing), this will classify your ground as 'ground' (class 2) and everything else as 1, then run las2dem https://rapidlasso.com/lastools/las2dem/ to convert the class 2 records only to a DEM. Lastools isn't free but it isn't expensive either, especially if you're a student or researcher.